# t-SNE High Dimension Data Visualisation

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, data-analysis

I have a twitter corpus which I am using to build sentiment analysis application. The corpus has 5k tweets which have been hand labelled as - negative, neutral or positive

To represent the text - I am using gensim word2vec pretrained vectors. Each word is mapped to 300 dimensions. For a tweet, I add all the word vectors to get a single 300 dim vectors. Thus every tweet is mapped to a single vector of 300 dimension.

I am visualizing my data using t-SNE (tsne python package). See attached image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E0Qf.jpg) - Red points = negative tweets, Blue points = neutral tweets and Green points = Positive tweets

[image: tweets represented using word2vec]

**Question:**
In the plot there no clear separation (boundary) among the data points. Can I assume this will also be the case with the original points in 300 Dimensions ?

i.e if points overlap in t-SNE graph then they also overlap in original space and vice-versa ?

Comment: With t-SNE, what is close in high-D will stay close, but of what is far apart in the visualisation, you don't know anything.

Answer (score 5):

Question: In the plot there no clear separation (boundary) among the data points. Can I assume this will also be the case with the original points in 300 Dimensions ?

In most cases NO. By reducing dimensions you will probably loose some information.
The case where you may reduce dimension without losing information is when or data in some dimensions is zero(for example line in 3dimensional space) or when some dimensions linearly dependent on other.

There are few tricks to test how good some dimensionality reductions techniques works. For example:

You may use PCA to reduce dimension form 300 to for example 10. You can calculate sum of 300 eigenvalues(original space) and sum of 10 biggest eigenvalues(these 10 eigenvalues represent eigenvectors that will be used for dimension reduction) and calculate percentage of lost information `sum(top-10-eigenvalues)/sum(300-eigenvalues)` .This value is not exactly "information" lost, but it is close to that.

Comment: I completely agree with you. But I have always seen a t-SNE visualization at the end of most blogs/articles on word vectors to "show" the goodness of these vectors. That what prompted me to ask the query